# Disable iPad Retina in Cocos2d v 3

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

In Cocos2d 2.0, I used below code to disable retina for iPad.

```
     if(!IS_IPAD)   //In AppController.m
     {
        [director_ enableRetinaDisplay:YES];
     }
```

Now AppDelegate not has these calls. How to disable retina for iPad only ?

Comment: Counter-question: why would you want to do that? You'll end up with an app that "doesn't look Retina" on Retina iPads which means if Apple considers the resulting image quality not appropriate for a Retina iPad they might just reject the app.

Comment: Its approved game with cocos2d 2.0. I got chance to port it to cocos2d 3. Is there any way like in 2.0 to avoid iPad hd ? Now a days game download mainly depends on app size..that is main reason why we avoid iPad hd.

Comment: You can alter the file extension and fallbacks used by CCFileUtils and I believe you just need to set the global contentScaleFactor on Retina iPad to 1.0. Check what enableRetinaDisplay does in v2, I believe it simply prevented the contentScaleFactor from taking on a value other than 1.0.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Got one simplest way - In setupCocos2dWithOptions added CCSetupTabletScale2X: @(YES). Now iPad HD uses iPad image without any problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to explore this. I do the same because i want to run all devices from a single set of textures ... and my textures are very 'potent' on all devices, looks fine.

this setup creates a ScreenViewPort that is constant size on all devices , 568x384. All my 'full background' textures are at 1136x768 pixels, able to display all devices. This simplifies layout drastically, but there is a small price to pay. World(0,0) is not ScreenViewPort(0,0). For example, when running on a 4in iPhone (568x320), ScreenViewPort bottom-left is at 0,32 , on an iPad it is at 28,0 ...

Our mileage may vary with new display sizes for iPhone 6, i'll cross that river when i get myself some devices and can ascertain the 'workability' of this.

in AppDelegate :

```
NSString *kCCFileUtilsSuffixDefault = @"default";
NSString *kCCFileUtilsSuffixiPad = @"ipad";
NSString *kCCFileUtilsSuffixiPadHD = @"ipadhd";  
NSString *kCCFileUtilsSuffixiPhone = @"iphone";
NSString *kCCFileUtilsSuffixiPhoneHD = @"iphonehd";
NSString *kCCFileUtilsSuffixiPhone5 = @"iphone5";
NSString *kCCFileUtilsSuffixiPhone5HD = @"iphone5hd";
//NSString *kCCFileUtilsSuffixMac = @"mac";
//NSString *kCCFileUtilsSuffixMacHD = @"machd";

NSDictionary *dic = [CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils].suffixesDict;
[dic setValue:@"-hd" forKey:kCCFileUtilsSuffixDefault];
[dic setValue:@"-hd" forKey:kCCFileUtilsSuffixiPhone];
[dic setValue:@"-hd" forKey:kCCFileUtilsSuffixiPad];
[dic setValue:@"-hd" forKey:kCCFileUtilsSuffixiPadHD];
[dic setValue:@"-hd" forKey:kCCFileUtilsSuffixiPhoneHD];
[dic setValue:@"-hd" forKey:kCCFileUtilsSuffixiPhone5];
[dic setValue:@"-hd" forKey:kCCFileUtilsSuffixiPhone5HD];

[self setupCocos2dWithOptions:@{
        // Show the FPS and draw call label.
        CCSetupShowDebugStats : @(YES),

        // More examples of options you might want to fiddle with:
        // (See CCAppDelegate.h for more information)
        // Use a 16 bit color buffer:
        // CCSetupPixelFormat: kEAGLColorFormatRGB565,

        // Use a simplified coordinate system that is shared across devices.
        CCSetupScreenMode : CCScreenModeFixed,

        // Run in landscape mode.
        CCSetupScreenOrientation : CCScreenOrientationLandscape,

        // Run at a reduced framerate.
        CCSetupAnimationInterval : @(1.0 / 30.0),

        // Run the fixed timestep extra fast.
        CCSetupFixedUpdateInterval : @(1.0 / 60.0),

        // Make iPad's act like they run at a 2x content scale. (iPad retina 4x)
       //       CCSetupTabletScale2X: @(YES),
}];

[CCTexture PVRImagesHavePremultipliedAlpha:YES];
```

and in CCFileUtils , a minor mod :)

```
-(CGFloat) contentScaleForKey:(NSString*)k inDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary{
    // XXX XXX Super Slow
    // ylb fix for single set of textures
    return 2.0f;
    // ylb fix : super fast now :)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick answer. I found 1 line fix. In setupCocos2dWithOptions added CCSetupTabletScale2X: @(YES). Now iPad HD uses iPad image without any problem :)

Comment: yep ... i need some fairly complex 'at runtime' layout for game menus as a function of device type, your fix was just one step short for me :)